# Concat scope in angular template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have three text boxes having scopes variable are  borderColor(`like #000000`),borderWidth(`like 3px`),borderStyle(`like solid`).I want to bind a div border if changes occur in one of these textboxes.I am using Angular.
This is what I did so far:

```
<div ng-style="{'border' : borderWidth+'px'+borderStyle+borderColor}">
This is my firtst div </div>
```

Basically, this is what I exactly want:

```
<div ng-style="{'border' : '3px solid #000000'}">
This is my firtst div </div>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no space between properties, try:

```
<div ng-style="{'border' : borderWidth+'px '+borderStyle+' '+borderColor}">
```

And one more. You have described "borderWidth(like 3px)" don't add extra `px` if it's already string like `3px`. Add px if it's `3`. Just a note to prevent `3pxpx`.